# Change font size in curved text with PIXI JS

Tags: javascript, text, mesh, pixi.js

Is there an easy way to change font size in PIXI JS curved text?
Text is created through `new PIXI.mesh.Rope(pixiText.texture, points)`.
With resize button (check image below) you can change size of object. I could use `scale` but it decreases quality.

In basic text object is possible to change font size `text.style.fontSize = newFontSize`.

[image: Tshirt]

Answer (score 0):

There is no super easy way like changing font size. The problem here is that letters generated via `Text` object use special mechanism, allowing it to rerender fast. To create mesh, you need texture and it can't be `Text` or `Graphics` object, because they are rendered from their own settings.

**There are two solutions:**

1. If there is limited space for user, You can try generate way bigger text and then generate mesh and scale it down, so even if user resize it, the text would still be in good enough resolution. This is quite easy to do, but it might not satisfy you or can be hard to implement in your case.
2. Way better solution, but harder to implement would be to update texture every frame or after user resized it. There are two ways to do it:

   - Use additonal canvas and paint text there to perform manual update (load new texture to gpu) or possibly use `text.resolution` property and update it in similar way
   - Use [RenderTexture](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/textures/render-texture-basic.js). This special texture allows to render any pixi objects into it, so what you can do is: create `Text` object and manipulate it with properties like you already did, create `RenderTexture` using this text or container with text and other needed elements and then use this texture to create mesh. If you do any update to your text, it will be automaticaly rendered into mesh using renderTexture.